# Can't move a folder despite it not being used - Windows | Python

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have encountered an issue where I have a file in Onedrive that I am not able to move. I have determined that, despite it saying that the `action cant be completed because the folder or file is open in another program`, it is not being used by another program.

I have come to this conclusion by using resource monitor to check which apps are using the folder. There are none besides file explorer.

[image]

Context as it's probably important:
The reason why this has happened is that i deleted a python venv in the file directory, resulting in my VS Code interpreter breaking. I have restored this venv file but the issue still has not been fixed. According to [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3535#issuecomment-450221780), it is the result of workspace links, however, I have never once used workspaces. The general idea that a file WITHIN that unmovable directory could be the reason though, and as a result, is possibly why this issue may be occuring. What does not make sense is why it is still happening even without VS Code running or any service connections being made as evident through resource monitor

Another thing to note is that the folder has not completely synced, however, based on past experience, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully moved the file via terminal, however the issue still remains about why i could not simply move the file with file explorer.